# Ironically Pushing Blank View Controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller

this is my first post on here, though with the help of many questions and answers from members of this community, I have brought my project to near completion.

I have read multiple threads similar to what I'm asking, but the methods were completely different.  No code has worked so far.

Basically (I say this because my code involves a lovely snake-like descent into a complicated mess, but applicable snippets will be put up upon request), my problem is that I'm calling

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and it pushes my viewcontroller in the simulator and NSLogs the string I need changed beautifully, but it pushes a blank view!  The code for that run makes the view controller variable a constant:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[xSheetMusicViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

So I thought to myself, what am I doing!?  So I went back to the old method, which involved making the UIViewcontroller an if-then, if-else-then statement that would push different views depending on whether certain rows were selected (standard stuff).  Which pushed a new view with my string loaded perfectly, but it only NSLog'ed one string over and over!  And the worst part was the my app would call either SIGABRT, or EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I tried returning to the rootviewcontroller. (here's the applicable code):

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[[UIViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
    appDelegate.baseURL = @"mussette.pdf";
viewcontroller = [[xSheetmusicViewController alloc]initwithnibname:nil bundle:nil];
}
else if (...)
//pushview, changestring, blah blah//
```

Now, I would prefer that my view push the PDF like it's supposed to, and have the correct string value (and not give me SIGABRT or EXC_BAD_ACESS, but those are givens), but it seems that compromise is just out of my reach.  I know there's probably something stupid I'm doing that could be solved with one line of code, but for now, it seems hopeless.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: To answer all of your questions, yes, there is no xib, rather an 
    (id)init
method in the next view.

EDIT 2: to answer lostInTransit's request and add some additional details:

```
<else if (indexPath.row == 1 && indexPath.section == 0) {
    appDelegate.baseURL = @"Importing PDF's.pdf";
```

Also, if it helps, the output keeps logging: 
    Application tried to push a nil view controller on target .

When I try to push the view from a tableviewcell, and it did that before when it loaded the PDF right so I ignored it.

Comment: why are you call initWithNbName:nil?  Do you have a XIB using interface builder or not?  If you are, why aren't you calling with @"myXibFileName"??

Comment: FWIW, if you pass `nil` as the nib name, it will automatically look for a nib named the same as the view controller’s class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question: why do you first initialize your viewController as a UIViewController and then again as xSheetmusicViewController? I think the problem is with releasing values properly. In one init, you do an autorelease, in the other you don't. So chances are you are releasing a variable twice leading to the BAD ACCESS.

Do you mind posting the "blah blah" :) in the last piece of code?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I only wish I could up vote it, but for now, you'll just have to settle for the check mark ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file named `xSheetmusicViewController.xib` in your application? That will be loaded with your view controller as its owner after you call `[[xSheetmusicViewController alloc] initNithNibName:nil bundle:nil];` (it will actually be loaded when the view property is first accessed). If that file doesn’t exist, then the view controller’s `-loadView:` method will be called to load its view.

If you have a blank view, either you have a blank or mis-named nib (perhaps you renamed the class but not the nib?) or you aren’t creating the right view in `-loadView:`.